# How do I zero-ise a secret key in java?

Tags: java, android, security, cryptography, secret-key

Is the following java code sufficient for clearing the secret key in memory (setting all of its byte value to 0)?

```
zerorize(SecretKey key)
{
    byte[] rawKey = key.getEncoded();
    Arrays.fill(rawKey, (byte) 0);
}
```

In other words, does the `getEncoded` method return a copy or reference to the actual key? If a copy is returned, then how can I clear the secret key as a security measure?

Answer (score 6):

Before trying to clear the key, you should check first if the implementation of the `SecretKey` interface also implements the `javax.security.auth.Destroyable` interface. If so, prefer that of course.

Comment: Only works in 1.8+ and usually just throws DestroyFailedException

Answer (score 4):

`getEncoded()` seems to mostly return a clone of the key (from the Oracle 1.6 source of for instance `javax.security.auth.kerberos`):

```
public final byte[] getEncoded() {
  if (destroyed)
    throw new IllegalStateException("This key is no longer valid");
  return (byte[])keyBytes.clone();
}
```

hence wiping the return data does not erase all copies of the key from memory.

The only way to wipe the key from the `SecretKey` is to cast it to `javax.security.auth.Destroyable` if it implements the interface and invoke the `destroy()` method:

```
public void destroy() throws DestroyFailedException {
  if (!destroyed) {
    destroyed = true;
    Arrays.fill(keyBytes, (byte) 0);
  }
}
```

Strangely enough it seems that all Key implementation do not implement `javax.security.auth.Destroyable`. `com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeKey` does not nor does `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec`used for AES. Both of these key implementations also clone the key in the `getEncoded` method. So it seems for these very common algorithms 3DES and AES we don't have a way to wipe the memory for the secret key?

Answer (score 2):

GetEncoded returns a copy of the secret key (so clearing that has no effect on the secret key data), and destroy by default throws DestroyFailedException which is worse than useless.  It is also only available in 1.8+ so Android is out of luck.  Here's a hack that uses introspection to (1) invoke destroy if available and does not throw an exception, otherwise (2) zero the key data and set the reference to null.

```
package kiss.cipher;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * Created by wmacevoy on 10/12/16.
 */
public class CloseableKey implements AutoCloseable {

    // forward portable to JDK 1.8 to destroy keys
    // but usable in older JDK's
    static final Method DESTROY;
    static final Field KEY;

    static {
        Method _destroy = null;

        Field _key = null;
        try {
            Method destroy = SecretKeySpec.class.getMethod("destroy");
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[16], "AES");
            destroy.invoke(key);
            _destroy = destroy;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        }

        try {
            _key = SecretKeySpec.class.getDeclaredField("key");
            _key.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException ex) {
        }

        DESTROY = _destroy;
        KEY = _key;
    }

    static void close(SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec) {
        if (secretKeySpec != null) {
            if (DESTROY != null) {
                try {
                    DESTROY.invoke(secretKeySpec);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("inconceivable: " + ex);
                }
            } else if (KEY != null) {
                try {
                    byte[] key = (byte[]) KEY.get(secretKeySpec);
                    Arrays.fill(key, (byte) 0);
                    KEY.set(secretKeySpec, null);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("inconceivable: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;

    CloseableKey(SecretKeySpec _secretKeySpec) {

        secretKeySpec = _secretKeySpec;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        close(secretKeySpec);
    }
}
```

The way to use this is like

```
try (CloseableKey key = 
       new CloseableKey(new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, 16, "AES"))) {
  aesecb.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key.secretKeySpec);
}
```

I use the Closeable interface because Destroyable is a 1.8+ feature only.  This version works on 1.7+ and is pretty efficient (it does a trial destroy on one key to decide to ever use it again).

Comment: This is a hack, and the GC can repack memory or OS move data to swap which may leak key data.  Close the key as soon as possible to minimize the possibility it leaks because of a GC or OS side effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that clearing `rawKey` will not affect the data in `key`.

I don't think there's a way in general to clear the data in a SecretKey. Specific implementation classes *may* provide for that, but I'm not aware of any that do. In Android, the risk of leaving the data uncleared is very low. Each app runs in its own process and its memory is not visible from outside.

I suppose there's an attack scenario where a root-priviledged process can take snapshots of memory and send them off to some supercomputer somewhere for analysis, hoping to discover someone's secret keys. But I've never heard of such an attack, and it strikes me as not competitive with other ways to gain access to a system. Is there a reason you are worried about this particular hypothetical vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the technology powering the garbage collector, any single object may be moved (i.e. copied) in physical memory at any time, so you cannot be sure that you will really destroy the key by zeroing an array -- assuming that you can access "the" array which holds the key, and not a copy thereof.

In shorter words: if your security model and context call for zeroing keys, then you should not use Java at all (or just about anything but C and assembly).

Comment: But if you have to use Java, zero it out quickly, before the GC is likely to repack data or the OS moves it to swap, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> ***In other words, does the getEncoded method return a copy or reference to the actual key?***

`key.getEncoded()` will return a *reference* to an array.

If the content of key is discarded when you do the Array.fill depends on whether or not the key is *backed* by the returned array. Given the documentation, it seems to me as if the *encoding* of the key is another representation of the key, i.e., that the key is *not* backed by the returned array.

It's easy to find out though. Try the following:

```
byte[] rawKey = key.getEncoded();
Arrays.fill(rawKey, (byte) 0);

byte[] again = key.getEncoded();
Log.d(Arrays.equals(rawKey, again));
```

If the output is `false`, you know that the key is still stored in `SecretKey`.

Answer (score -1):

Except primitive values, everything else in Java is always passed by reference, including arrays, so yes, you are clearing the given byte array correctly.

However, SecretKey class probably still holds data needed to generate that byte array, there including eventually another copy of the given byte array, so you should investigate how to clear that data as well.

Comment: -1: *everything else in Java is always passed by reference* -- Nooo, Java is *always* pass by value! The reason you can't pass *an object* by value, is because no variable can contain an object in the first place!

Comment: @aioobe .. you sure we are talking about the same Java? int is passed by value, boolean is passed by value, Integer is a reference, as well as any object, array etc... Java passes "a value", which is actually a "reference" to an object, so it is by reference.

Comment: @Joachim .. I was referring to "the given byte array", however further clarified that there could be another copy.

Comment: @SimoneGianni: please ignore my previous comment, I was braindead. But aioobe is right: Passing a reference by value is **not the same thing** as passing something by reference.

Comment: @aioobe: Your comment is a bit misleading. Indeed in Java everything gets *passed by value*, both primitive types and *object references*. Indeed variables can hold only references to objects, not the objects themselves. But that's quite confusing without [an explanation](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

Comment: @SimoneGianni, yep. I'm quite sure we're talking about the same Java :-)  Read Joachim Sauers excellent comment and maaartinus article. I know, sorry about that. I couldn't fit an explanation in the comment, and was too lazy to do what you did ;-) thanks.

Comment: @aioobe, i get your point, and it's academically correct, however we're not helping this guy with such a discussion here. He's asking wether that byte array is actually a local copy or a reference, and it is actually a reference, despite the fact that in pascal parameters are references to references. However Joris Wit is right and i voted for him, if it implements Destroyable, after clearing the byte array as already done, calling its destroy() method.

Comment: @Simone - It doesn't help OP to know it's a reference. The question is, a reference to _what_? In particular, is it a reference to the internal data of the secret key or a reference to a copy of the data? OP wants to know if clearing out the array will clear out the sensitive data in the key.

Answer (score -4):

Taking a slightly different tack, once you have identified the correct area of memory to overwrite, you might want to do it more than once:

```
zerorize(SecretKey key)
{
    byte[] rawKey = key.getEncoded();
    Arrays.fill(rawKey, (byte) 0xFF);
    Arrays.fill(rawKey, (byte) 0xAA);
    Arrays.fill(rawKey, (byte) 0x55);
    Arrays.fill(rawKey, (byte) 0x00);
}
```

Comment: As depicted above, `key.getEncoded();` only returns a copy, so you are deleting `nil` here..