# Zero-fill Android device internal memory

Tags: android

After taking backup of Contacts and other information. I want to zerofill the internal memory (In order to wipe-out the data completely). The device is 'rooted'. But, little confused on where to start & how to start. Can somebody provide some information with code snippets to do it.

The memory is where data is stored should be reset with zeros.

Comment: Its quite possible. Requesting people who knows it to comment.

Comment: This is about as close as you can get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191906/how-do-i-zero-ise-a-secret-key-in-java

Comment: This is so that a file that is deleted is not recoverable?

Comment: @Nathan that is quite different one.

Comment: @Nathan its not just over writing a file. There is a technique called zerofill. Google yourself for information, which will be used for erasing the date in hard disk.

Comment: phones use emmc memory, since wear leveling is enabled on these devices, you can never guarantee that zero filling will do a secure erase, so you should format the whole partition using secure erase emmc command, if you have root access

Comment: @nandeesh, yes i have root access. But want to know how to do secure erase. Can you share some code with us.

Comment: It depends on the type of emmc available on the device. You need to refer the data sheet of emmc and issue the ioctl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/sdcard/zero"});

process.waitFor();
```

Comment: Where to execute this? How to execute this? Please explain, don't just throw a piece of code without a context.